# Database is not deploying when deploy in Google app engine through eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am deploying a app in Google app engine. It has deployed successfully but database is not deploying.I have developed this app in java using Google app engine.
                         When i see the data in data store Viewer in app dashboard so it not showing any thing.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Google App Engine in a long time, but I don't think it's MEANT to be deployed - after the initial deployment this is obviously an issue as you don't want to overwrite your production data.

This post may help: [Google AppEngine database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203901/google-appengine-database)

Answer (score 1):

Matt Salmon is right, your local datastore and the remote one are two different things. In order to start seeing stuff in the datastore viewer online you will have to interact with the deployed application and start inserting data. Since you manage to have some data locally, you should be able to do the same online.

Also your local datastore will be reseted from time to time, but if you want it not to be deleted then run your development server with an argument: `--datastore_path=` and if you're also using the blobstore: `--blobstore_path=DIR`.