# Don't see updated datastore with entities even the debuging the code passes successfully without errors

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Datastore is not being updated even there's no errors. My code is:

```
package com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.server;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.DelistedException;
import com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockPrice;
import com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockPriceService;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

public class StockPriceServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        StockPriceService {

    @Override
    public String getPrices(ArrayList<StockPrice> stocksData) throws DelistedException {

        DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

        Entity stock = new Entity("Stock", 1);
        stock.setProperty("Stock", "FCB");

        ds.put(stock);
        return "ahoie";
    }

}
```

What could be the reason for that?

Is here something missing in configuration at eclipse or google app engine online?

I've noticed what it works and shows data locally: 127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/admin But web datastore admin console at https://appengine.google.com is not updated even if I deploy my app to the app engines cloud

Comment: How do you know it's not updated?

Comment: Are you sure that your Entity is "Stock"? The Entity usually will not be the same as a key. See [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity)

Comment: are you sure this isnt about eventual consistency in datastore?

Comment: I login to my account with google engine and see datastore dashboard and Query windows are empty

Comment: The web console sometimes shows old state. Try to use your application to fetch the entity.

Comment: I've noticed what it works and shows data locally: http://127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/admin/  But web console is not updated even if I deploy my app to the app engines cloud

Comment: Tried to fetch data when app is deployed in the cloud and it does not get it. Locally everything works good.